# SwingUtilities.invokeLater() vs EventQueue.invokeLater()

Tags: java, swing

Are there any differences between `EventQueue.invokeLater()` and `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`?

Or  is that the latter is just built on top of the former (with no modifications) for the sake of design?

Answer (score 81):

### No there is no difference.

[SwingUtilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) class was built to combine all general utility methods used in swing to be in one single class. Internally `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` calls `EventQueue.invokeLater()`

```
1197    public static void invokeLater(Runnable   doRun) {
1198       EventQueue.invokeLater(doRun);
1199    }
```

Reference: http://kickjava.com/src/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.java.htm