# EventQueue.invokeLater vrs SwingUtilities.invokeLater

Tags: java, swing, awt, eventqueue, swingutilities

Can someone highlight on the differences between these two and the instances both are required?!

I have an application which uses both intercheably, but want to know if one is better than the other. Obviously they both accept `Runnable object`, and so for me - I think I can use which one I like.

Why these two similar functions in different classes? I know one is in awt and the other Swing, but don't they do the same thing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SwingUtilities.invokeLater() vs EventQueue.invokeLater()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847083/swingutilities-invokelater-vs-eventqueue-invokelater)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`SwingUtilities.invokeLater` exists only because `EventQueue.invokelater` was introduced in 1.2, but Swing was available for 1.1. Swing in the JRE has always just called the `EventQueue` version. `swingall.jar` had some hack where it created a component, and executed pending operations on repaints.

`invokeLater` is about the `EventQueue`. I suggest using the method directly. `SwingUtilities` is just a dumping ground. I have seen a lot using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` presumably in some kind of belief the Swing isn't dependent upon AWT.

Answer (score 5):

Actually the code of **SwingUtilities#invokeLater(Runnable doRun)** is :

```
public static void invokeLater(Runnable doRun) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(doRun);
}
```

So it's exactly the same thing!

Answer (score 4):

As described in the javadoc, they are the same, e.g. a copy-paste from the `invokeAndWait` method javadoc

> As of 1.3 this method is just a cover for java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait()

So you can mix them and it does not matter which version you use.