# Difference between SwingUtilities Threads and AWT.EventQueue threads

Tags: java, swing, awt, swingutilities, event-queue

I am using using the Netbeans 7 IDE to develop a GUI desktop application.
  When I create the JFrame class , Netbeans uses the

java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {  }

To initiate the runnable object.
But my application has swing components as well.

I will like to know the difference between the

```
 java.awt.EventQueue threads
```

and

```
SwingUtilities threads
```

for GUI application development.

Comment: Possible duplicate [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333525/eventqueue-invokelater-vrs-swingutilities-invokelater)

Comment: `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` is still with us for historic reasons only, to maintain backwards compatibility. Apart from that, they are the same thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SwingUtilities.invokeLater() vs EventQueue.invokeLater()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847083/swingutilities-invokelater-vs-eventqueue-invokelater)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

> As of 1.3 `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` method is just a cover for
>   java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater().

Also the source of SwingUtilities [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.java#SwingUtilities.invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

```
public static void invokeLater(Runnable doRun) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(doRun);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Both are actually the same. `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` directly calls `EventQueue.invokeLater` ([ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)).

> As of 1.3 this method is just a cover for
>   `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater().`